# Blog Layout, duplicate content and SEO

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, blog

I am wondering wether my blog content can be considered as duplicated by search engines. Here is my situatuion, each article can be fully displayed on **4  different urls** :

1. **Blog layout** : 2 full articles on the "news" page `http://example.com/news`
2. **Article page** : `http://example.com/news/article`
3. **Archives** (1 page/month with 2-3 full articles) : `http://example.com/archives`
4. **Archive article page** : `http://example.com/archives/article`

For the 4th point, I am planning to use the `rel="canonical"` link to tell search engines witch page I want to index.

But I am pretty puzzled about the 3 first points. Would it be better (for SEO purpose) to change the structure of my blog and not display the full article in the blog layout?

For the archives, should I set meta tag to `noindex` to avoid duplicating the articles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Rel=Canonical Pass PR from Links or Just Fix Dup Content](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5457/does-rel-canonical-pass-pr-from-links-or-just-fix-dup-content)

Comment: on the other hand, if you implemented canonical links you wouldn't need to use noindex as canonical indicates it is a duplicate (that is if the link doesn't point to itself)

Comment: @LiamSorsby I can use canonical link on the `archives/article` page but not on the `archives` page as it is not a copy of an other page , it just features articles from several other pages.

Comment: **Don't use noindex**! Don't you want seo value for older entries?

Comment: @web-tiki if it's not a duplicate then there wouldn't be any need to use canonical link tags so you would be fine for this.

Comment: @LiamSorsby it is duplicate because the content displayed in `archives` is already displayed on other pages

Comment: @Martijn I Though of using `noindex` on the archive layout witch displays content from other pages so the older entries would still have values

Comment: @web-tiki duplicate means the entire content of the page is exactly the same as another page. Is the entire content of the page exactly the same? Otherwise it's like saying i have a header footer and sidebars all throughout my site, it is duplicate content

Comment: @LiamSorsby I had never thought of it that way, but you got a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question and the comments. With respect to all of the commenters who all left excellent comments from my point of view, I think there is a missing element in these considerations. Small, but important.

Your News and Archives pages will have more than one full article each and I assume other things too. It will not be an exact copy of your article in that respect. However, you still have the same problem. Sorta. As well, from the Article and Archive Article pages, I am sure that an article will age from one location to the other and so that would not be an issue.

So between /article and /archive I do not see a problem. But on the News and Archives pages, I do. Somewhat.

Here is what I am thinking.

I would not post the entire article on the News and Archives pages, but I like what you want to do, so I would suggest perhaps a larger portion of the article than just a snippet. Just for an example, if possible, perhaps half or a third of the article. I do not know what options your blog software gives you, or even if you can write code to help manage the appearance of your blog, but I would (from a programming perspective) take the first x number of characters from each article and make them available on your News and Archives pages. Assuming that most articles are at least 300 words, you should be able to take a good chunk of the article, something on the order of 1/3rd or 1/2 and post it with safety. As much as I do not like the *read more* links, perhaps that would be a good idea.

If this is not possible or is not an option you want, then I think you *may* have little choice but to *no index* the News and Archives pages *unless* these pages change rapidly. If this is the case, then you *may* not have a worry. If these pages change rapidly enough, then I assume that Google would mark these pages as having duplicate content. If you do *no index* these pages, then I would make sure there is a sitemap to make sure that your archived articles get indexed and that when an article moves from /article to /archives, that a 301 redirect handles this move for you.

Just some simple thoughts on the matter. You appear to have a nice scenario in mind. The question is, what is the best way to handle it. It may be that your setup will work fine without modification and you will not see any issues. But to know that for sure, you will have to try it. If you want to be sure there is not a problem, then I would suggest a sitemap and *no index* the News and Archives pages.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, I am considering cutting the articles and adding that undesired "read more" link. I didnt' want it at the bigining to prevent having to come back one step each time the article is read but it would at least make visitors go further in the site herarchy and would prevent duplicate content. SEO can get pretty anoing sometimes(most of the time).

Comment: I have to admit using a *sorta* read more link where I use the article title with read more. While they are necessary, I just feel they are over used. That is all. Not a big deal. One nice advantage is that you will increase your *time on site* per user and *pages read* per user. These are important metrics for Google to help rank your site. I suspect this is why the read more links are used as much as they are.

Comment: @closetnoc I wouldn't no index the news portion of the site, isn't this the first place the article would reside? Hence the article won't get index until it is archived at least!

Comment: I was kinda mixed on this. It is possible that Google would see the pages changing rapidly enough that it would not matter. Also I was not sure of the blog scenario, but I was assuming that the article would appear on the Archive page and still have it's own page. Same assumption with News. With this assumption, it was not necessary to have the News and Archive pages indexed. It is always an option not to use the *no index* and just see what happens. I suspect it would be fine. But I wanted to couch my answer on the side of caution. Otherwise, you may be right!